# Android searchview add a parameter in the onQueryTextChange method

Tags: android, parameters, parameter-passing, searchview, android-search

I need to pass a parameter in the "onQueryTextChange" method, like I did in the LoadMoreTask, the "npagina" is an Integer... parameters, I need to do the same in the  "onQueryTextChange", but it doesn't let me, because of the "OnQueryTextListener" class. Is there an alternative way to do that?

```
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(Menus.PROCURAR));
        if (searchView != null) {
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String submit) {
//                    showResults(submit, 1);
                    return false;

                }

                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String change) {

                    //TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (searchCheck) {
                        showResults();


                        try {


                            clientes = new ArrayList<ClienteModel>();
                            Repositorio mRepositorio = new Repositorio(getActivity());
                            List Clientes = mRepositorio.getClientes(change, 15, 1);

                            clientes = Clientes;
                            ads = new ClientSearchViewAdapter(getActivity(), this, clientes);



                            lv.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
                                    new LoadMoreClientTask(progressBar, FragmentClientes.this, ad, getActivity()).execute(1);
                                    System.out.println("PAGE " + page);
                                }
                            });

                            new LoadMoreClientTask(progressBar, this, ad, getActivity()).execute(1);

                            lv.setAdapter(ads);


                            System.out.println("Pesquisa: " + clientes);


                        }catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });


        }

        searchView.setQueryHint(this.getString(R.string.search));

        ((EditText)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text))
        .setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

        menu.findItem(Menus.PROCURAR).setVisible(true);

        searchCheck = true;


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case Menus.PROCURAR:
            searchCheck = true;
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }



    private void showResults() {

        try {


            progressBar = new ProgressBar(getActivity(), null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyle);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams progressBarParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            progressBar.setLayoutParams(progressBarParams);
            progressBar.setPadding(6, 6, 6, 6);
            footerLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            AbsListView.LayoutParams layoutParams = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            footerLinearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            footerLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            footerLinearLayout.addView(progressBar);

                lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listaClientes);

                clientes = new ArrayList<ClienteModel>();
                ad = new ClientViewAdapter(getActivity(), this, clientes);


                lv.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
                lv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

                lv.setAdapter(ad);



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

LoadMoreTask:

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... parameters) {
        int npagina = parameters[0];
        cliente= new ArrayList<ClienteModel>();

        try {

            Repositorio mRepositorio = new Repositorio(context);


            List listaDeClientes = mRepositorio.getClientes("", 5, npagina);

            cliente = listaDeClientes;


            System.out.println("pagina " + npagina);

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: create a class that implements OnQueryTextListener and pass some parameters in the ctor

Comment: @pskink ctor==constructor?

Comment: yes, ctor == constructor

Comment: @pskink I'm not understanding it very well, can you give an example on how it works?

Comment: @pskink How come implementing OnQueryTextListener will allow me to create a parameter in the onQueryTextChange method? I'm sorry for the noob question, but I'm new to Android Development

Comment: onQueryTextChange has only one parameter: a String with your query,  how do you want it to have more parameters?

Comment: @pskink because I need to pass the number of the pages like I did in the LoadMoreTask, see " int npagina = parameters[0];"

Comment: so as i said create a class that implements OnQueryTextListener and pass this parameter in the constructor